# Looking for a Dwarf Galaxy < 500 L.y. in Diameter, which is not a Satellite / Companion, or is at least 500 000 L.y. away from another Galaxy

Tags: galaxy, galactic-dynamics, intergalactic-space, dwarf-galaxy

My goal is to learn about an example of a Dwarf Spheroidal or a Dwarf Irregular Galaxy which is not a Satellite / Companion Galaxy (or is at least 500 000 L.y. away from another Galaxy), and doesn't measure more than 500 Light years in Diameter.

I must say that merely learning whether such Galaxies exist or not, would also be extremely helpful.

Another great alternative would be a Galaxy of any shape as long as it's less than 500 L.y. in Diameter and at least 500 000 L.y. away from another Galaxy.

The perfect example however would be a Dwarf Spheroidal or a Dwarf Irregular below 500 L.y. in Diameter, at about the average distance away from another Galaxy.

I found a few lists of Dwarf Galaxies, but they are lacking details regarding the sizes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.